# deluge "open folder" uses wrong application

Tags: linux, bittorrent, file-types, deluge, xdg

while `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` returns `enlightenment_filemanager.desktop`

I'd want deluge open folder to use enlightenment file manager.

is there a way to "reverse" the xdg-mine query command and see what are the file types associated with thunar.desktop ?

is it possible that it's the debian package that uses thunar by default (dunno how deluge sets the open folder command) ?

Version: 1.3.12-1

Answer (score 0):

ok it seems that .local/share/applications/defaults.list was overrifing my settings, so removed it :) and now it works as intended